Why is consciousness deemed to be an entity of some kind or concept when it may simply be the act of observing objective reality through the mind?
If in the quantum realm observation is the factor that determines the collapse of the wave function into generating form and reality, then is consciousness not simply the act of the mind observing objective reality at a quantum level and subsequently generating a humanist, subjective reality as a result?
In this way consciousness is not an entity or collective of brain processes at a macroscopic scale but simply the process of observing objective reality and creating subjectivity.

How does the act of observing objective reality come out of objective reality? If objective reality is just that then what is there to "observe" it? An "act" needs an actor, without that it is just an event where nothing can "observe" anything. Consciousness comes up in explaining how a subject (observer) comes out of object (observed). "Through the mind" just replaces the word with its equivalent, "consciousness" with "mind", and explains nothing.

@Conifold - "How does the act of observing objective reality come out of objective reality?" Hm, haven't we evolved from what was in origin "dumb" matter? Are you saying that the mind is something sui generis and therefore inexplicable? (I wonder what you think of https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/13259/1/Strange%20Inversion%20and%20Making%20sense.pdf)

@ajsmith15 - What does quantum physics have to do with consciousness? Homo sapiens is not directly observing quantum reality. (Are you referring to Penrose's Orch?)

@mudskipper If it was sui generis and inexplicable why would we put so much effort into explicating it? "Evolving" from a non-answer does not thereby provide a solution, namely a reduction/explication in this case, or even a plausible sketch of it.

In (a) dreams (b) delirium (c) psychodrugs like LSD,  consciousness is very much there. Is the observed reality there objective reality?

simply the process of observing objective reality and creating subjectivity  - but WHAT is doing the observing? Surely THAT is the consciousness we are seeking to define?

Wait.  What about people born blind?  They observe nothing, but experience reality.

We are not conscious of the quantum aspect of the phenomenon we observe.  And quantum behavior is so counterintuitive that very few of us can ever really grasp quantum theory.  The idea that quantum interactions are intrinsically enmeshed with consciousness, has no actual reason or justification to be considered.
The one neural event I know of that is explicitly a quantum interaction is photodetection in our rods and cones.  But we are unaware of these specific quantum events.  Our rods and cones are instead explicitly unconscious.    Vision is instead an integrated "story" assembled and presented to our consciousness, with cues and highlights to focus our attention on specific features of the visual field. So -- testing this hypothesis -- is pretty much a failure.


Quantum systems make the transition from the word of possibilities
to one distinct state during the observation (Collapse of the wave function).
But that does not mean
that the trigger is the human observation. Instead, it is the interaction with other systems on the
macroscoping scale. In physical terms: The reason is the ongoing process of
decoherence.
In a radical form this idea has been elaborated by Carlo Rovelli. For an introduction into the whole area see Relational Quantum Mechanics.

The fact, that certain mental processes are experienced as being
conscious, is a phenomenon located and studied by neuroscience on a
level totally different from quantum mechanics.
A good introduction is Christof Koch: Consciousness.


